# What is known about the equation $x^2+ay^2=b^2$, where $a$ is a fixed square free positive integer and $b$ is a fixed positive integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

$(b,0)$ and $(-b,0)$ are two trivial solutions. What do we know about the nontrivial solutions of the equation $x^2+ay^2=b^2$.

Comment: The only time $x^2+y^2=b^2$ has a unique solution is when $b=0$. So...

Comment: Factor as (x + sqrt(a)y i)(x - sqrt(a) y i). Lookup quadratic integers and also Pell's Equation.

Answer (score 4):

Let us write it as
$$  x^2 + a y^2 - z^2  = 0 $$
Theorem in Mordell, Diophantine Equations. Theorem 4, page 47, all solutions with
$$  \gcd(x,y,z) = 1$$
come in a few  parametrizations of the Pythagorean Triple  type. On average, it gets more complicated as the (binary) class number gets large.
I always do a reality check on a prospective list.

For example, $x^2+ 14 y^2 = z^2.$  We have, at least, one recipe with $z = u^2 + 14 v^2,$  you can probably work out the recipes for $x$ and $y.$  On the other hand, we can have $z = 2 u^2 + 7 v^2$ and new $x,y$

Gets  new types when $h(-4a) $ is divisible by $3$.
We could have $z = u^2 + 11 v^2.$  We get something different by taking $z = 3 u^2 + 2uv + 4 v^2$  Let me check some things...

.[image]

On average, more such recipes are needed

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer..